# Setting permission for mounted folder - How to add write permission for group?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mount

I mounted my windows device's folder to a ubuntu instance and cannot grant it group write permission:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 user     user      4096 Jul 15 10:25 new
drwxrwxr-x 4 user2    user2     4096 Jul 16 22:10 downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 vidsuser vidsgroup 20480 Jul 17 08:31 archives
```

I tried a couple things eg:
sudo chgrp -R vidsgroup .archives
sudo chmod g+w ./archives
sudo chmod g+rwx ./archives/

the archives folder is the mount point and I cant change the permissions for this. What could I do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Comment: sry about that, I thought I was posting in unix & linux